# Inserting Data into Excel using Cell References rather than indexing

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I'm having an export excel method in my c# code. Earlier I was inserting data into each cells as

```
WorksheetObj.Cells[rowvalue,colvalue] = "something";
```

But, Is there a way to insert data into cell using Cell reference, like

```
WorksheetObj.Cells["A",1] = "Something";
```

I'm using Excel Interop for the export functionality.

This might be a duplicate, but, I didn't find such solution or post regarding this..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WorksheetObj.Range["A1"].Value2 = "Something";
```